# Converting from LESS to CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert LESS nested CSS to standard CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896500/convert-less-nested-css-to-standard-css)

I'm using a new `framework` ***[Site Link](http://320press.com/wpbs/)*** but the problem is it was developed using `LESS`.

It also included `CSS` files, so I thought I would be able to simply delete the `LESS` files and be okay - however, when I did that, I would lose most of my **styling**.

Does anyone have a solution on the best way to achieve this? Most of the people i work with have yet to learn `LESS` so I need a `framework` we can work on as a team.

Comment: Possible dupliacate [Convert LESS nested CSS to standard CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896500/convert-less-nested-css-to-standard-css)

Comment: LESS is a superset of CSS isn't it? they could still write standard CSS in a LESS file, no?

Comment: Now check to this link and convert to your css http://lessjs.orangecluster.com/

Comment: @user1645074: You may check [Simpless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)

Answer (score 3):

From the [http://lesscss.org/ home page](http://lesscss.org/), it actually comes with a default compiler to go from less to CSS;

---

Less comes with a binary, which lets you invoke the compiler from the command-line, as such:

```
$ lessc styles.less
```

This will output the compiled CSS to stdout, you may then redirect it to a file of your choice:

```
$ lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

---